# What is the sum of the first $42$ terms of the sequence?

Tags: arithmetic

> The sum of the first $14$ terms of an arithmetic sequence is $2014$. If the sum of the first $28$ terms of the same sequence is $2014$, what is the sum of the first $42$ terms of the sequence?

I thought the sum would be the same ($2014$) since it didn't change from the $14$ term sum to the $28$ term sum.

Comment: You can deduce that the sum of terms 15 to 28 is 0.

Comment: Right. Then how do I get the sum of the next terms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum of the first 14 terms is $2014$, the sum of the next 14 terms is $0$, and then the sum of the next 14 terms is $-2014$.

And the sum of
$$2014 + 0 + (-2014) = 0$$

---

This is because the sequence of 
$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
(a+0d)& +&(a+1d)& + \cdots +& (a+13d),\\
(a+14d)& +&(a+15d)& + \cdots +& (a+27d),\\
(a+28d)& +&(a+29d)& + \cdots +& (a+41d),\\
&&\vdots
\end{array}$$
are in AP with term difference $14^2 d$.

Comment: How did you get term difference $14^2d$?

Comment: If you notice there are $14$ values for each row and a constant difference of $14d$, which makes for a total of $14*14d$ which is $(14)^2d$

Comment: Okay, I see that the third row is $14^2*d$ greater than the second row. How does this mean it's sum is $-2014$?

Comment: So the first row adds to $2014$; the second row adds to $0$, which is $2014$ less than the first. And the third row should also adds to be $2014$ less than $0$.

Comment: Oh I see why now. It's because $14^2d$ is -2014 right?

Comment: @Puzzled417 Right.${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Yes that was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If you group terms of an arithmetic sequence $k$ at a time (in non-overlapping groups), and you form a sequence of the sum of those groupings of $k$ terms, that new sequence will be arithmetic.

Comment: That's the easiest way. Also works with overlapping groups.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: since the sum of terms $15$ to $28$ is zero, so is their average, which is the value of term $"21\frac 12"=\cfrac {15+28}2$. Let the difference between successive terms be $2d$ - you should be able to write down terms $21$ and $22$ and work from there. Having found that zero value, exploit the symmetry.